# Manipulate HTML dom in PHP

Tags: php, html, dom

Is there a way to do this? I would like to replace one element with another but somehow it isn't possible in PHP. Got the following code (the $content is valid html5 in my real code but took off some stuff to make the code shorter.):

```
$content='<!DOCTYPE html>
<content></content>
</html>';

$with='<img class="fullsize" src="/slide-01.jpg" />';
function replaceCustom($content,$with) {
  @$document = DOMDocument::loadHTML($content);
  $source = $document->getElementsByTagName("content")->item(0);
  if(!$source){
    return $content;
  }
  $fragment = $document->createDocumentFragment();
  $document->validate();
  $fragment->appendXML($with);
  $source->parentNode->replaceChild($fragment, $source);

  $document->formatOutput = TRUE;


  $content = $document->saveHTML();
  return $content;
}
echo replaceCustom($content,$with);
```

If I replace the `<img class="fullsize" src="/slide-01.jpg" />` with `<img class="fullsize" src="/slide-01.jpg">` then the content tag gets replaced with an empty string. Even though the img without closing tag is perfectly valid html it won't work because PHP only seems to support xml. All example code I've seen make use of the appendXML to create a documentFragment from a string but there is no HTML equivalent.

Is there a way to do this so it won't fail with valid HTML but invalid XML?

Comment: Would a string replace or regular expression replace not be easier?

Comment: Your code seems to work for me.  I'm not sure what the problem is.

Comment: Which PHP version are you using?

Comment: @ExplosionPills remove the self closing part of the image tag and the content element will be replaced with an empty string.

Comment: Self-closing `<img>` tags _are_ valid HTML...

Comment: @Spudley using version 5.4.17

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`DOMDocumentFragment::appendXML` indead requires *XML* in my version (5.4.20, libxml2 Version 2.8.0). You have mainly 2 options:

1. Provide valid XML to the function (so a self closing tag like `<img />`.
2. Go 'the long way around', as suggested by the manual:

> If you want to stick to the standards, you will have to create a temporary DOMDocument with a dummy root and then loop through the child nodes of the root of your XML data to append them.

```
$tempDoc = new DOMDocument();
$tempDoc->loadHTML('<html><body>'.$with.'</body></html>');
$body = $tempDoc->getElementsByTagName('body')->item(0);
foreach($body->childNodes as $node){
   $newNode = $document->importNode($node, true);
   $source->parentNode->insertBefore($newNode,$source);
}
$source->parentNode->removeChild($source);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, works in the example but still won't load content from wordpress posts, these are custom posts containing nested html like a menu wrapper and menu items. Or slider wrapper and slider items. Current code will add each child of $body's body but not the children of these children so I end up with 3 empty div's for slider items.

Comment: Oh, excuse me, I omitted the `,true` in `importNode()` (in which case it makes a _deep_ copy) and then it works.

Comment: I see now, just found it in the documents. First had to find out where my html was. Just posted a comment to indicate that deep has to be provided but see you already made that comment. Thank you for your help, I will use DOMDocument to try and get nested content in there.

Comment: And edit for `,true`, to `,True`? Really? The [often used PSR-2](https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/accepted/PSR-2-coding-style-guide.md) states: _"The PHP constants true, false, and null MUST be in lower case."_. But it depends on which standard you follow ;)

Comment: Ah sorry, had an unrelated problem and thought PHP didn't accept lower case true and false. Thought I fixed it with changing the first character to upper case as in the docs http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php At that time I just glanced over it and didn't notice the docs actually say that case doesn't matter. Don't use PHP very much as you can see.